# MS Access Columns and sums

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I'm stuck on a bit of a Doozy here.
I'm trying to formulate a column in MS Access where it takes the rows with the same order number from Column A, and sums up those two same row value in column b and input into Column C

I'm relatively new to MS Access but familiar with SQL writing

Perhaps that doesn't make sense
but let me illustrate the columns for you

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |

| Order 01 | $10      |   $45    |

| Order 01 | $15      |  $45     |

| Order 01 | $20      |   $45    |

| Order 02 | $300     |   $350   |

| Order 02 | $50      |  $350    |
```

Column C Is sum of all that is the same names in Column A
Any help on how the SQL would be written or the design view in MS Access would be done would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB,
       (select sum(ColumnB)
        from table1 as t2
        where t2.ColumnA = t.ColumnA
       ) as ColumnC
from table1 as t;
```

This calculates the third column for your result set.